# Can't generate Signed Bundle on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, google-play, android-app-bundle

How can I generate a signed bundle?

I want to upload a signed app bundle of Flutter project to Google Play.

**Environment**

[image: Android Studio version]

**What I did**

1. Go to Build > Flutter > Build App Bundle
2. Create an aab file and upload it to Google Play.
3. Get this message: "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode."
4. Go to this page (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#signing-manually)
5. Find this instruction: "click Build > Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK".
6. However, I don't find "Generate Signed Bundle/APK" in "build". (I got stuck here.)

[image: Menu]

[image: Google Play error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sign Android apps written in Flutter, you can follow Flutter's signing method which can be used with `flutter` command line interface. If `build.gradle` is configured correctly, you can use `flutter build appbundle` (considering you want to generate an appbundle, not an apk) to generate an appbundle. Take a look at [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) page for detailed information.

Answer (score 6):

You should open `android` folder of your flutter project in android studio. Not root directory.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

You need to click on **`Build->Generate`** Signed APK/Bundle in the android studio. Even the **`DEBUG`** applications get signed with a **`DEBUG Key`** for the purpose for testing by the developers on emulators or real devices by installing it through ADB.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for release signing, for some reason.